# What is "Midas"?

Tags: terminology

I've recently noticed the term "midas" creep up in crypto currency related conversations, in phrases like "might implement midas".

Can anybody enlighten me on what this is, preferably with links.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Found it, it's the codename for Mt Gox's new trading engine

> Our new trading engine is finished and soon to be deployed after a couple of hardware updates. Code-named "Midas", we're currently bench-testing the engine at over 500,000 trades per second, but Midas is capable of much more than that. We're really looking forward to showing you what it can do, and are pretty certain you'll love it too.

source https://www.mtgox.com/press_release_20130805.html